Getting a 403 error when trying to access the dashboard
From the frontend, a request is sent to the server. If the data is correct, the user is redirected to their dashboard (in this case, the admin page). The HTML file of this page sends a GET request to the controller along with the JWT token retrieved from a cookie. Here is the code of the page:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Admin Office Page</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Admin Office</h1>
    <script>
        function getJwtTokenFromCookie() {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            let jwtToken = null;
            cookies.forEach(cookie => {
                const parts = cookie.split('=');
                const name = parts[0].trim();
                const value = parts[1] ? parts[1].trim() : '';
                if (name === 'JWT_TOKEN') {
                    jwtToken = value;
                }
            });
            return jwtToken;
        }
        const jwtToken = getJwtTokenFromCookie();
        console.log('JWT Token:', jwtToken);
        if (jwtToken) {
            const headers = {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`
            };
            console.log('Request headers:', headers);
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/admin_office', { headers })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('Server response:', response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log('JWT Token not found in cookies.');
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

When I allow access to /admin_office in WebSecurityConfig (.antMatchers("/admin_office/**").permitAll()), as shown in the code below,
    @Configuration
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Slf4j
    public class WebSecurityConfig {
        private final JWTTokenConfig jwtTokenConfig;
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .cors().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                            .antMatchers("/host_page", "/register", "/login",         "/music_files").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/*", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/personal_office/**").authenticated()
                            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/main").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/free_subscription").hasAnyRole("FREE", "OPTIMAL", "MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                            .antMatchers("/optimal_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "OPTIMAL", "ADMIN")
                            .antMatchers("/maximum_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                            .antMatchers("/admin_office/**").permitAll()
                            //.antMatchers("/admin_office/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore((Filter) jwtTokenConfig,         UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
        }
    }

I see that there is an authentication header with a JWT token:
    GET /admin_office HTTP/1.1
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
    Accept-Language: uk,uk-UA;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6
    Authorization: Bearer         eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTkyNTMxNDQsImlhdCI6MT        cxOTI1MDE0NH0.uE0Udi4vmYqmEw9ONpW0lpIUHWRFK4yfxwZvGUgzXl4
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: Idea-4b25f4ef=61bb4bd3-acaa-48f6-a981-7d36d9342587; XSRF-TOKEN=8f2e4045-e028-4522-        8b27-91fe42f6c2ae; JSESSIONID=BCEC9B62DF292BBD69ACB107F692B9FA;         JWT_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTkyNTMxNDQs        ImlhdCI6MTcxOTI1MDE0NH0.uE0Udi4vmYqmEw9ONpW0lpIUHWRFK4yfxwZvGUgzXl4
    Host: localhost:8080
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/admin_office
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like         Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    X-XSRF-TOKEN: 8f2e4045-e028-4522-8b27-91fe42f6c2ae
    sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

But when I restrict access to /admin_office (.antMatchers("/admin_office/**").hasRole("ADMIN")):
    @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .cors().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                            .antMatchers("/host_page", "/register", "/login",         "/music_files").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/*", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/personal_office/**").authenticated()
                            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/main").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/free_subscription").hasAnyRole("FREE", "OPTIMAL", "MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                            .antMatchers("/optimal_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "OPTIMAL", "ADMIN")
                            .antMatchers("/maximum_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                            //.antMatchers("/admin_office/**").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/admin_office/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore((Filter) jwtTokenConfig,         UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
        }

I receive a 403 error on the frontend. The request looks like this:
    GET /admin_office HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
    Accept-Language: uk,uk-UA;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: Idea-4b25f4ef=61bb4bd3-acaa-48f6-a981-7d36d9342587; XSRF-TOKEN=8f2e4045-e028-4522-        8b27-91fe42f6c2ae; JSESSIONID=BCEC9B62DF292BBD69ACB107F692B9FA;         JWT_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTkyNTQ5ODYs        ImlhdCI6MTcxOTI1MTk4Nn0.gcxzXYncPCI4rCj1m1Uaaex66380KgAGsKjYeSxzaj8
    Host: localhost:8080
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/host_page
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like         Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

On the backend, everything is working. Below is the HTML file of the page that redirects to the user's dashboard:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="/login">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required><br><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber, password: password })
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.redirected) {
                window.location.href = response.url;
            } else if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                return response.json().then(error => {
                    throw new Error(error.message);
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('Login failed: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

and my JWTTokenConfig:
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class JWTTokenConfig extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        private final JWTService jwtService;
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse         response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            String username = null;
            String jwt = null;
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
                try {
                    username = jwtService.extractUserName(jwt);
                } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                    log.debug("Token lifetime has expired");
                } catch (SignatureException e) {
                    log.debug("The signature is incorrect");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.debug("Error parsing token: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtService.getRoles(jwt).stream()
                        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                log.info("User {} with roles {}", username, authorities);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new         UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        username,
                       null,
                        authorities
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

The frontend is open in Google Chrome.
Where could the reason be?

When decoding the JWT token of your example, the role displayed is:
"roles": [
    "ROLE_ADMIN"
]

So it seems you need to look for the role "ROLE_ADMIN" instead of "ADMIN".

When I send a GET request to http://localhost:8080/admin_office in Postman with this token:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTkzMTc3ODUsImlhdCI6MTcxOTMxNDc4NX0.TTLgnAXXMR67qLgNKxHG-UInEjXQVQWT6fOgBVHWeTQ,
I receive a 200 status code. However, when I use the token without the ROLE_ prefix, like this:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiQURNSU4iXSwiZXhwIjoxNzE5MzE4MDY2LCJpYXQiOjE3MTkzMTUwNjZ9.vVF6rjVbTGDETnB6VsqTf-U-Gw9DNE-0nKz9RJ3mblk,
I get a 403 status code. I think my error might be somewhere on the frontend.

I think the reason is hidden here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78673188/it-is-necessary-to-send-the-jwt-token-from-the-browser-page-to-the-server
