It is necessary to send the JWT token from the browser page to the server
When I send a GET request to retrieve the page in Postman along with the authorization header, I see the following in the console logs:
    2024-06-26 17:33:53.036  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Filter starts
    2024-06-26 17:33:53.037  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Jwt Token: Bearer         eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTk0MTE4MDYsImlhdCI6MTcx        OTQwODgwNn0.YOdWUsdkTl4E4ucZ1gjk8sAYKaBMxrsVET5m6rnRXEg
    2024-06-26 17:33:53.037  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Received JWT token:         eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTk0MTE4MDYsImlhdCI6MTcx        OTQwODgwNn0.YOdWUsdkTl4E4ucZ1gjk8sAYKaBMxrsVET5m6rnRXEg

That is, my configuration filter is called once and receives the token. But when I refresh the page in the browser, here is its HTML code:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Admin Office Page</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Admin Office</h1>
    <script>
     function getCookie(name) {
      let cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");

      for(let i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
        let cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");

        if(name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
          return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
        }
      }

      return null;
    }
    let jwtToken = getCookie("JWT_TOKEN");
    console.log('token '+jwtToken);


    fetch('/admin_office', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Server response:',jwtToken );
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error sending token to server:', error);
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

I see the following in the logs:
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.160  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Filter starts
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.162  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Jwt Token: null
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.195  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Filter starts
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.195  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Jwt Token: Bearer         eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTk0MTUwODYsImlhdCI6MT        cxOTQxMjA4Nn0.Uwgj-5TuQnFtRxOQBnSVkIiBzTv4hg9swbAXHRX7dec
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.196  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Received JWT token:         eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjE3MTk0MTUwODYsImlhdCI6MT        cxOTQxMjA4Nn0.Uwgj-5TuQnFtRxOQBnSVkIiBzTv4hg9swbAXHRX7dec
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.201  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-6]         u.d.PetMusicStorage.service.JWTService   : Parsed roles from token: [ROLE_ADMIN]
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.201  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : Filter starts
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.202  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig            : Jwt Token: null
    2024-06-26 17:40:50.203  INFO 6856 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] u.d.P.security.JWTTokenConfig                    : User 1 with roles [ROLE_ADMIN]

My configuration filter is called three times, and the JWT token is obtained on the second call. When I make this endpoint protected, the filter is called only once, but the token is not obtained, and I get a 403 error on the frontend. I think the reason is that the request from the frontend first fetches the entire HTML file from the server and then sends the script request. I haven't delved deeply into JavaScript and HTML yet, so if possible, please explain or, if possible, write the code where the token is immediately sent from the frontend to the server. That is, first the frontend sends the token, and if it is valid, it opens the page. If not, a 403 error is returned.
Everything works on the backend! Access to protected endpoints with a valid token is available.

If the request requires authentication, then yes, you have to include the JWT Bearer token in the request. Note that you have to do this manually - the browser will not automatically include it for you as it does cookies.

But my script retrieves the token and sends it along with the GET request, and this is visible in the logs. I think the reason is that the browser wants to load the page first, and only then execute the JavaScript code. Is it possible to structure the HTML file so that the script for sending the token is called first?  https://i.sstatic.net/lGuOtV9F.png

"Is it neccessary" - why not try it out and see if your application works without the token?

It works without the token, but this is an educational project. I want to figure out and understand how it works on the front end.

I found the reason/error on my backend. I was reading from the header in the filter, but I needed to read from the cookie. Here's a code snippet in case someone needs it:
     String authHeader = Arrays.stream(request.getCookies())
                .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals("JWT_TOKEN"))
                .findAny()
                .map(c -> "Bearer " + c.getValue())
                .orElse(null);

